# Knockout with IE8- losing click binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

Using Knockout v2.3.0:

I have a section where I'm binding to a model using "with: modelName".

In that section, I've built a number incrementer:

1. grey button with a minus on it
2. input field showing the value,
3. grey button with a plus on it

Basically, as you'd expect, clicking the minus decrements the counter, while clicking on the plus, increments it.

It works perfectly in all browsers, except for IE8 (perhaps IE7, too).

In IE8, it works fine with a clear cache.  However, if you refresh the page, that first button non longer works.  Basically, there's no click binding at all on that field on subsequent page loads.

I was initially trying to have each button use the same function and passing a different string: "down" vs "up".   But I thought IE couldn't handle this, for some reason.

So, now, I've built out separate functions:  decrementChildCount() and incrementChildCount().

But the same thing happens.  IE8 is fine on loading the page from a cleared cache.  But subsequent page loads makes it lose the click binding- only for the first button.

Another thing I found when I added a cleaner version of the markup just above the original ones (so I'd have two sets of button-field-button groups).

Now, the very first button loses its click binding, but all others work fine- even the original minus button, since it is no longer the first button in the section.  That minus button now works fine on subsequent page loads.

What's up with this?  Why would the very first click-bound button lose it's click binding on subsequent page loads?

And to solve this I really don't want to have a dummy click-bound button that gets hidden, just to get the "real" first button to work....

-- Scott

Comment: If [this minimal fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UC4Pg/) works for you on IE8, it's not really an IE8 problem. (I highly doubt that anyway.)

Comment: oh, i can see it in full-page mode.  But it works just fine in IE8.  bummer.

Comment: I have had a with binding around a jquery file upload and it worked fine in IE9 and FF but in IE8 it did not. If you look at my profile you can find the question but I had to just add the model name to all of my data binds.

Comment: Thanks.  Everything works fine, except for a couple of little issues.  I can hack around this one by putting in a hidden button with the same binding. Since that button is first, it is the target of the missing click handler, so my REAL one continues to work fine.

Comment: I think it's best you set up a fiddle that shows this problem. I can't believe the issue is rooted in IE, it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this to find your issue in the short term and come up with a solution to rectify it long term -

Change your data-bind to this -

```
data-bind="with: $data.modelName"
```

Which will show nothing if modelName is null and modelName if it is not.

Next, the pretag to see when or why it is going away -

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: It shows exactly what I'm expecting.  If the click event is working, the resulting other DOM changes (new elements via templates) work just fine.  And they show the same results as is represented in the $data json.  The problem isn't the data, it's that there's no click event on the first clickable button.